# HTTP Json requests in C++?

Tags: c++, json, http, post, httpwebrequest

How to make HTTP Json requests in C++? Any library? Under "HTTP Json request" I mean make POST with Json object as data and receive result as Json.

Comment: cURL and whatever json.org has for C++.

Comment: Why the close vote? Ok, the question may be expanded a little, but I don't think that "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here".

Comment: @Matteo: There are so many constraints that might need to be considered that the question is really difficult to answer. For example, saying "use sockets for the networking, and sprintf to fill out the request" would match the question as stated, but is unlikely what the OP wants to hear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [libCURL](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) to get the actual JSON data. Then parse it with some C++ library like [jsoncpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/).