# how to put URL in InetAddress.getAllByName?

Tags: java

I have a problem. I want to display all address by URL, kind **https://google.com**, but I get an error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: This host is unknown (https://google.com)`
I know that by entering a regular domain (like **google.com**) into getAllByNAME , everything will work. Help me solve this problem please

My code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
        InetAddress[] inetAddress = InetAddress.getAllByName("https://google.com");
        for (InetAddress key : inetAddress){
            System.out.println(key.getHostAddress());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I know that by entering a regular domain (like google.com) into getAllByNAME , everything will work."* - It sounds like you've already found the solution... ?

Comment: @David but I need to insert a URL into this method, not a regular domain

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getAllByName(java.lang.String)) specifies that the method expects a *host name*, not a complete URL.  What you have here is called an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).  You'll need to address why you **think** you "need" to do this and adjust your approach accordingly.  For example, you can write your own method which accepts a complete URL, parses out the host name, and uses that host name for this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are giving a complete URI with protocol (`https://`) while only the domain is requested. The function is basically trying to resolve something that is not a domain name, so it does not work.

You can only use it with domain names (so the same as your URI, but without the protocol), like you pointed out with `google.com`.

If you need to split the URI, you can use the split function, or do as explained here : [Java URL Without Protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22740582/java-url-without-protocol)