# How to make post curl request in java

Tags: jsp, servlets, curl

This is my curl request.

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
--header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'apikey: xxxx' -d 
'name=abcd&email=test@test.com.com&id=abc' 
'https://api.gupshup.io/appsdk/api/components/adduser'
```

Can anybody help me, how to send it using java servlet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP Json requests in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474293/http-json-requests-in-java)

Comment: What do you mean by "send it using java servlet"? Do you want to do the same query but in Java?

Comment: yes,i want to send it by java

Comment: Hi Nicolas sorry for delay. Do i need to add any library for Webb Class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I were you I would use [DavidWebb](https://github.com/hgoebl/DavidWebb) a lightweight Java HTTP-Client for calling JSON REST-Services and proceed as next:

```
Webb webb = Webb.create();
JSONObject result = webb
    .post("https://api.gupshup.io/appsdk/api/components/adduser")
    .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    .header("apikey", "xxxx")
    .body("name=abcd&email=test@test.com.com&id=abc")
    .asJsonObject()
    .getBody();
```

Comment: Which library need to add for Webb class

Comment: @IrshadQureshi This one http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.goebl%7Cdavid-webb%7C1.3.0%7Cjar

Comment: honestly i didt'n understand how to use it in my java web application