# Java Http request PUT : 401 unauthorized

Tags: java, httprequest, put, http-status-code-401

I'm trying to send a PUT request from a Java app to a server. I successfully send GET, POST and DELETE requests but the PUT one won't succeed (I'm getting a 401 Error with the code below, 405 Error with an other code using the HttpPut of the apache package).
I'm using java.net.HttpURLConnection, here is a small region of my code :

```
URL obj = new URL(urlPost);

HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

//add request header
con.setRequestMethod(typeRequest); //typeRequest = PUT

String credentials = adminOC + ":" + pwdOC;
String encoding = Base64.encode(credentials.getBytes("UTF-8"));
con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", String.format("Basic %s", encoding));

if (!typeRequest.equals("GET")){
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    try (DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream())) {
        wr.writeBytes(postParam);
        wr.flush();
    }
}
if (con.getResponseCode() == 200){
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()))) {
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response += inputLine;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried sending my PUT parameters the "POST" way and also directly in the URL.
It seems to be an error from my Java code and not from the server because I tried to do the PUT request with cURL and it worked.

Thanks for reading, I hope you will be able to give me some hints to debug the problem.

Comment: could you do it with curl?

Comment: where do you set the method name to PUT?

Comment: @Nicolas Yes, the following curl cmd works fine : curl -X "PUT" -u login:pwd http://myadress/testdeploy/ocs/v1.php/cloud/users/john -d key="email" -d value="john@example.org"

Comment: And the method name is stored in typeRequest (which is a parameter of my function and is set to "PUT" in the execution context)

Comment: what is postParam ?

Comment: @Nicolas postParam (String) is here "key=email&value=john@example.org" (for example, to replicate the cURL example)

Comment: use OutputStreamWriter with an encoding instead of DataOutputStream

Comment: also set Content-Type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded and Content-Length

Comment: To ease your live you could use DavidWebb as described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/36479644/1997376, indeed it supports the put method and parse the result for you

Comment: Thanks for you time @Nicolas . I'll try all the things you advised me, have a good day

Comment: The problem was the Content-Type not set. Big thanks

Comment: I put it as reponse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is missing in your code is `con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")`